# The data of assigns gets lost when a button is clicked in a modal

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I save "current_user" to the **session** variable in a plug. And I have the **standard, auto-generated** form-component or modal of LiveView.  I'm using a modal in a part of a website where only authenticated users are allowed.

router:

```
    live_session :on_authenticated, on_mount: MyWebsiteWeb123.InitLiveassignss do
      scope "/", MyWebsiteWeb123 do
        pipe_through :browser

        live "/abc", MyLive
      end
    end
```

init assignss module:

```
    defmodule MyWebsiteWeb123.InitLiveassignss do
      import Phoenix.LiveView

      def on_mount(:on_authenticated, _params, session, socket) do
        cu = Repo.get!(User, session["current_user_id"])
        socket2 = assigns(socket, :current_user, cu)

        {:cont, socket2}
      end
    end
```

This nicely allows me to get access to the `current_user` in socket in the situations when "submit" button is clicked, in a **normal** form on a page.

However, not in a modal. That is, not when "save" button is clicked in it -- 'current_user' gets dissapered.

```
    //current user is nil
    def handle_event("save", %{"my_model" => my_model_params}, socket) do
      // 'current_user' doesn't exist anywhere in 'socket'
      a1 = socket.assigns[:current_user]

      //
      //a2 = socket.assigns[:current_user_id]
      //a3 = socket.assigns["current_user"]
      //a4 = socket.assigns["current_user_id"]
      //a5 = socket["current_user_id"]
      //a6 = ...........

      //......
    end
```

Where has `current_user` has disappered from `assigns` in a modal?

How to make all this work?

Comment: Have you checked if you're matching the on_mount with inspect or a fallback/default function?

Comment: Is this modal just HTML in the live view? If not, and it's a live component, be sure to use preload or update to pass on the assign from live view to the live component.

Comment: @thelastinuit it's live component. Right. But why is it that it's not described anywhere? Everywhere it says that I simply am able to get access to assigns directly -- from a live view, in a live component. Namely, I don't have to pass anything to live component additionaly

Comment: Yeah, It is like implicit. When you call a component you can do like so: <.live_component module={MODULE} {assigns} />. It means it's passing ALL assigns (which btw it's not recommended). So, you can call it as <.live_component module={MODULE} current_user={assigns.current_user} />. That means, ONLY current_user will be passed on to the live component. assigns.current_user, that assigns it's from the live view where you are mounting the live component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since it's a live component. Follow [this](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.LiveComponent.html).
Namely:

```
<.live_component module={YourLiveComponent} id="live-component-id" current_user={@current_user} />
```

you can call @current_user because HEEX's assigns from live view is defined by your on_mount.

Comment: I've followed that. Where in that is it described?

Comment: Right before the section Life-cycle: "You must always pass the module and id attributes. The id will be available as an assign and it must be used to uniquely identify the component. All other attributes will be available as assigns inside the LiveComponent."

Comment: All the assigns become @ by HEEX sigil, btw. in your case live view at render function. those assigns are passed on to the html template where you probably are loading the live component. you can access assigns or their respective name with @. whatever you pass on to live component will be accesible at the preload or update function of the live component.